# read the value of an element

Tags: jquery

How to extract the value of **strong** element In the following code.

```
    $(e).find("div[id^='edit']").each(function(index, element) {
           // The "element" contains a <strong>NUM</strong> tag. Extract NUM
    }
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: jquery `text()` should work. `$(element).find("strong").text()`

Comment: add strong did't work? `"div[id^='edit'] strong"` with `+$(this).text()` inside the each

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$(e).find("div[id^='edit']").each(function(index, element) {
     var num = +($(this).find("strong").text());
});
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the meaning of `div[id^='edit'`

Comment: @rocking `div[id^='edit']` selects all `div`s whose `id` starts with the text `edit`.

Comment: @JLRishe Could you please tell what does the "+" do. And also what does the **this** refer to.

Comment: @JLRishe the Unary `+` is like `parseInt(num, 10)`, it just converts and String representation to `Number`. `+"2" === 2`